# Trying to create a new drive under a user MsGraph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to make a Post to add a new Drive to an already existing user but I am getting request invalid. I don't know if I am missing something or if it is not possible.

```
var createNewDrive = await graphServiceClient
    .Users["5715609d-b9b6-471a-b337-bdc9a98dca2f"]
    .Drives
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(new Drive() 
    {
        Name = "PleaseWork",
        DriveType = "documentLibrary"
    })
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

#1 - First get the list of drives for the user. This will give the list of all drives for the given user.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com/drives

#2 - Now look for the newly created drive for the user by checking it's ID's or display name. Here i assume that i have the id for the newly created drive (say either i got it from the delta or captured the ID when the new drive is created).

say, id: b!-RIj2DuyvEyV1T4NlOaMHk8XkS_I8MdFlUCq1BlcjgmhRfAj3-Z8RY2VpuvV_tpd

#3, Now get the items from the above drive:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com/drives/b!-RIj2DuyvEyV1T4NlOaMHk8XkS_I8MdFlUCq1BlcjgmhRfAj3-Z8RY2VpuvV_tpd

Here's the documentation for [getting the onedrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) or [list the drives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Also here's the C# code as well:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var drive = await graphClient.Users["MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"].Drives["b!-RIj2DuyvEyV1T4NlOaMHk8XkS_I8MdFlUCq1BlcjgmhRfAj3-Z8RY2VpuvV_tpd"]
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

Comment: To be more clear, I am not trying to create a new oneDrive, but a new drive under an already existing user.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... let me revise my answer above :)

Comment: Apologies for the delay, but this isn't what I was looking for. So what I need is a way to create a new documentLibrary (Drive) under a 'user' (Onedrive). I have managed to do this for a 'site', but I can't seem to find a way to do the same for a 'user' (Onedrive). I would also want to point out that I have managed to do a workaround where I got the underlying 'site id' of the user's onedrive and then create the documentLibrary (Drive) using that 'site id', but I am trying to avoid this.